# Checking if a stream is empty

Tags: c#, .net, stream, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a XML-file. I need to check if the XML-file stream is empty before tying to deserialize it.

```
IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs1 = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("test.xml", 
    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, isf);

// Deserialize the XML to an object
Settings s = new Settings();
SoapFormatter SF= new SoapFormatter();
s = (Settings) SF.Deserialize(isfs1);
```

How can I check if `isfs1` empty or not?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Check the [`Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefilestream.length.aspx) property of the stream.

> Length represents the number of bytes currently in the file.

If it is 0, the file is empty.

Answer (score 7):

If your file is in UTF-8 format, it's size is at least 3 because of BOM(Byte Order Mark). So checking the length > 0 will return true even if your file is empty.

Comment: so? what's the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Would [IsolatedStorageFileStream.Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefilestream.length.aspx) work?

```
if (isfs1.Length > 0) {
  // isfs1 isn't empty.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you construct empty zip archive memory stream it have 22 bytes in empty state.

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
{
    // no content added
}
memoryStream.Length // have value of 22
```

Answer (score 0):

if isfs1.Length =0 means the stream is empty